# How to change Angular bootstrap UI popover trigger event in different devices like tab, mobile etc?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created a popover which will trigger on mouse hover. For the desktop purpose it is good:

```
<p popover="template" popover-placement="left" popover-trigger='mouseenter'>Help</p>
```

My question is how can I make text "Help" as a link if I use the same code in tablet or mobile? So that in mobile or tab if I click on help then it will open the popup?

This is my plunker link: [Popover example](https://plnkr.co/edit/INBwOeHvIiKvi6A2h7Y3?p=preview)

Comment: Have a look at this: http://solidlystated.com/scripting/bootstrap-popover-multiple-triggers/

Comment: The ui-bootstrap popover works fine also on mobile and popover-trigger="mouseenter" works as tap event trigger (check also the note on docs https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover)

Comment: @beaver you mean the same code will work fine in tab and mobile as well?

Comment: @Alok Yes, I've tried with an Android device and it works fine: your popover is triggered on tap.

Comment: @beaver Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add ui.bootstrap library in your app from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

and just put html code and configure code as per your requirement.

```
<button uib-popover="I am activated manually" popover-is-open="popoverIsOpen" ng-click="popoverIsOpen = !popoverIsOpen" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Toggle popover</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you taken a look at tooltip from Angular-UI: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ at `ui.bootstrap.tooltip`

It included both hover and click functionality as opposed to the popover which is usually just one of the two.

EDIT: 
You are using an old version. Doc: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/

Example:

```
<a href="#" tooltip="I can have a custom class applied to me!" tooltip-class="customClass">Check me out!</a>
```